# Git semantic commit versioning for file deletions

Tags: git, naming-standards, conventions

What commit type should I use when I'm deleting files from a repo?

I have seen several types over the internet, but none talk about file deletions.
Possibly the closest options that come to mind are **CHORE** and **REFACTOR**.

**EDIT 1 : START**

Reasons why I'm confused is because none of the definitions for **CHORE** and **REFACTOR** talk about file deletions.

Internet gives below definitions,

**CHORE:**

`chore: (updating grunt tasks etc; no production code change).`

[This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26944762/when-to-use-chore-as-type-of-commit-message) throws some more light on its possible usages.

**REFACTOR**

`refactor: A code change that neither fixes a bug nor adds a feature`

As per [this SO post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/225829/276993) file deletions don't come under Refactoring.

I believe the descriptions of `REFACTOR` need to be improved in the documentations. Deletion is such a common thing that I would expect it to be there in the definitions of `REFACTOR`ing.

I might be overthinking. I just want to do what is right.

**EDIT 1 : END**

Answer (score 1):

This relates to https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/ ?

The semantics are supposed to describe *why* rather than *what*. So it depends why you're deleting the files.

Comment: This is a good start, but can you elaborate on your last sentence?

Comment: @pjc50 That site is one of the many that I referred to. I get your point of WHY i.e. the intent behind the file deletion. In my case I had added few files during development but then moments later discovered that they were not required and hence deleted them. These files are present in last two commits.

So from the Angular convention referred in that doc `refactor: A code change that neither fixes a bug nor adds a feature` , it appears REFACTOR should be used. But then again its not a code change; its complete removal of the files themselves.
And this why its confusing.

Comment: You're overthinking this. One of the major achievements of Git is to make renaming, moving, deleting etc. of files as transparent as editing of file contents. Don't complicate things by re-introducing an artificial distinction between the two. Removing files from a directory should be treated exactly like removing lines from a file.

Comment: I might be overthinking. I just wanted to do what is right.

Comment: I believe the descriptions of `REFACTOR` need to be improved in the documentations. Deletion is such a common thing that I would expect it to be there in the definitions of `REFACTORing`. As per [this SO post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/225829/276993) file deletions don't come under Refactoring. Why then do you suggest it's same as removing lines of code. To the downvoters: care to explain `why`?

Comment: " In my case I had added few files during development but then moments later discovered that they were not required and hence deleted them. These files are present in last two commits." : squash the commits?

Comment: @pjc50 Thank you so much. I can get rid of the files from past commits. Anyways I will be squashing and merging during PR. That's not the actual concern. I just wanted to know what's the best fit for commit type in case of file deletions.

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick, did you read https://www.conventionalcommits.org/en/v1.0.0/#how-does-conventional-commits-handle-revert-commits?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Thank you but that talks about reverting commit(s). I don't understand how reverting commits is same as just deleting few files and committing them. I am not concerned about previous commits. Also, I think this discussion is deviating from my original concern. What I am concerned about is what `commit type` should be provided if I `delete` files. I'm not adding a feature or anything. I'm just deleting the files and that is what I just want to commit(and I do wish to provide a commit message for that, with an  appropriate type). Contd...

Comment: Let's also ignore the scenario where we would be removing the files from the previous commits. I am just looking for an appropriate `commit type` as per the semantic versioning/conventions(if at all there exists any) that covers the case of file deletions.

Comment: @AsifKamranMalick, why are you removing those files? In a previous comment you hinted that it was because some files were not needed after all. In that case you are reverting the action of adding them and a `revert` commit is appropriate. If the files became unused due to a refactoring, then it would be a `refactor` commit. Those are the two commit types that most likely involve deleting stuff.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Thank you. That's quite an insightful perspective. I understand that `REVERT` is meant for reverting commits, but that in essence means reverting full changes that were part of those commits. I'm not trying to delete everything that was part of earlier commit(s), instead I am just deleting few of the several files that were part of those commits. So I'm not at all trying to revert commits. `REFACTOR` doesn't fit in the use case where the files were added just for future purpose(no relation at all with existing codes) and then were later removed. Did I misread your comment?